# How can i read the excel file in Azure Web API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, cloud-business-apps

I have Create Azure Web API and Hosted it on to the Azure App Service.

In this Azure Web API method I want to read the Excel documents or Excel sheet from the SharePoint Online site, and for that I have tried to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` dll but it doesn't work.

It gives me the below error.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly

Please help me to read the Excel document in Azure Web API using C# code.